# can't get loop in mysql_fetch_array to print on separate lines

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to loop through my mysql query result and print out some of the data. What I expected was when I added "\n" to the end of the print message, it would print each message on a separate line. But for some reason its all on one line. Why is this and how can I make each message be on a separate line?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    $message = $row['action_type'] . " " . $row['identifier'] . " @ " . " placeholder ";
    if($row['location'] !== NULL)
    {
        $message += " on " . $row['location'] . "\n";
    }
    echo $message . "\n";


}
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: eh, "\n", lol..Use <br /> the headers are HTML not plain text.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$message` variable is ending with a `/n` when it should be `\n`. Try updating it to fix (unless of course, in that section of the code it's on purpose):

```
$message += " on " . $row['location'] . "\n";
```

The actual `echo` statement ends with a real newline, so this should work properly in a command-line, but not in a browser.

To get it to display on a new line in a browser, change the `\n` instances to `<br />`:

```
echo $message . "<br />";
```

Comment: Or wrap the output in a `<pre>` tag

Comment: @bfavaretto Makes a great point; to have the newlines display in HTML, you could also wrap the entire output block in `<pre></pre>` tags too!